# Mobile Backend API REST Security

Tags: api, security

I have an API REST that acts as gateway between mobile device and other four or five microservices (REST APIs, too). All of this components are hosted in Amazon EC2.

I don't know much about this and I would like to know the possible solutions to protect from external connections this components. I want each microservice to be accesible only from the gateway API REST.

Which technique should I apply? Restriction by IP? Between mobile device and the gateway API REST I'm using Client/Secret through HTTPS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For security purpose, you should use OAuth 2.0 for API. So, unless the user is registered to your system, he won't have an access token and thus can't access your API.

If you are doing restriction based on IP, then tomorrow if your API is consumed by let's say 1000 unique user, are you going to save those IP in your system, which I don't think a efficient way to do.

> Two Factor Authentication

Along with OAuth, you can also implement Asymmetric Cryptography, so that the user will get encrypted data, and if user has public key then he can decrypt the response. So, if any invalid user has an access token, he will get data but it won't be useful.

**But**

Compared to symmetric encryption, asymmetric encryption imposes a high computational burden, and tends to be much slower. Thus, it isn’t typically employed to protect payload data. Instead, its major strength is its ability to establish a secure channel over a non-secure medium (for example, the Internet). This is accomplished by the exchange of public keys, which can only be used to encrypt data. The complementary private key, which is never shared, is used to decrypt.

One more thing, use HTTP Method POST for API.

[[Additional Info]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/where-to-start-with-api-security-testing/89318#89318)

Comment: Thanks. I will use OAuth2 between mobile device and API gateway. But, what about the gateway against microservices? I don't want the users can access to microservices. Only gateway API must can. Should I construct a DMZ or something similar?

Comment: I haven't implemented DMZ type functionality, but yes you might need to implement that or some kind of Handshake between Consumer API and microservices.

Comment: Thank you again. What about "make your API to return response only when there is a POST request" ? Why did you say that?

Comment: When you're calling an API, either it will be a GET/POST (if you just want data listing, else it will be PUT/PATCH in case of Update and DELETE for deletion). So, in GET call parameters are visible in URL + has a length limitation. I am not saying that for POST call you can't see which parameter you posted, it's more secure way in case of API(s).